# Libgdx Box2D bounds

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I have a body that during the game will be falling and can be moved left and right, but it needs to stay within the camera's bounds (basically not going off the screen). The camera follows the Y position of the body but stays fixed on 0 for it's X position. What is the best method to prevent the body from going outside of these bounds?

Comment: You could setup fixed bodies on the sides (like walls) so the box will collide with them I guess.

Comment: I tried doing something like that and while that worked while the body is not falling, I need to move them along with the body while it is falling, which seems to be generally frowned upon in the box2d community, so I was wondering if there was a better/proper way.

Comment: Well, I suppose you can detect when the body is leaving the area and then apply a force in the opposite direction.